# Easiest way to reduce the size of a contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm almost done with my contract but I've done (almost) everything to reduce the byte size of my contract and I'm still missing like two features. That's why I need to split the contract in order to reduce size even more. I've already extracted a part of my code into two other contracts. `Bar` is abstract and will be extended by my main contract and `Baz` will be initialized and called from the main contract. Example:

```
contract Foo extends Bar {
  Baz baz;

  constructor() {
    baz = new Baz();
  }
}
```

That worked out but my contract size didn't really decrease. Should I inject `Baz` instead of initializing it on the main contract? How would I do that since something like that

```
contract Foo extends Bar {
  Baz baz;

  constructor(address barAdress) {
    baz = address;
  }
}
```

will throw `Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type contract Baz.` obviously.

Does an extended abstract contract even reduce the byte code or will it be combined in compilation and result in the same size?

Comment: Sharing another answer for optimizations: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99971/what-does-enable-optimization-mean-in-remix-and-what-does-it-do

Answer (score 3):

> *Does an extended abstract contract even reduce the byte code or will it be combined in compilation and result in the same size?*

The compiler still needs to include the abstract contract, so it doesn't reduce the final bytecode size.

An effective way to reduce the bytecode size is to use the compiler **optimization** option. The value specifies the number of the contract runs that it should optimize for (not the number of optimization iterations). So lower values will result in smaller bytecode but also higher gas fees each time you're executing a function.

Comment: already have that set to 1

Comment: Thank you @Petr Hejda for your clear explanation. Continuing with the bytecode size optimization discussion, is this explanation extended to interfaces? I looked into https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.8/using-the-compiler.html, but there is no related info. I assume that the compiler only extracts from interfaces the functions called in the contract via interface, the rest are not necesary to be included in the bytecode.

Comment: Yes, it extends to interfaces as well. When you're using an interface in Solidity code, the resulting bytecode contains a condition that the result of the call needs to have a predefined length - otherwise it pushes the "revert" opcode to the stack.